# create an array from a part of a hash in perl

Tags: perl

I have a hash which contain sub hash, I want to abstract that sub hash separately and create a array from that,

hash look like

```
'a1' => '1',

'a2' => '2'.

'Def' => [
            'd' => 'x',
            'e' => 'y'
         ]
```

I need to make a separate hash for 'Def'. and print only 'Def' as a array

Comment: i am disappointed that i am not able to clearly describe my question, i just want to know that can we create a new hash from a existing hash which include some part of that hash,

Comment: Have you looked at the Perl FAQs? There is a whole set dedicated to manipulating data structures: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html

Comment: it would be useful to show both your input and what you expect in the output. Also a little extract of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hard from reading your question to know just exactly what you are trying to achieve but my interpretation of it is that you want to extract the anonymous hash allocated to def and store it in another hash. Then you want to print this hash as an array. I have also included examples to print just the keys of the values of the hash.

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my %first_hash = (
    a1 => '1',
    a2 => '2',
    def => {
        d => 'x',
        e => 'y'
    }
);

my %second_hash = %{$first_hash{'def'}};
my @full_array = %second_hash;
my @keys_array = keys %second_hash;
my @values_array = values %second_hash;

print Dumper (\%first_hash);
print Dumper (\%second_hash);
print "full array: ", join(' ',@full_array), "\n";
print "keys array: ", join(' ',@keys_array), "\n";
print "values array: ", join(' ',@values_array), "\n";
```

**OUTPUT**

```
$VAR1 = {
          'a2' => '2',
          'def' => {
                     'e' => 'y',
                     'd' => 'x'
                   },
          'a1' => '1'
        };
$VAR1 = {
          'e' => 'y',
          'd' => 'x'
        };
full array: e y d x
keys array: e d
values array: y x
```

Answer (score 0):

Below you'll find the answer.

```
print "@{$a{'Def'}}";
```

Comment: this is not working , error comes  Global symbol "%VersionRef" requires explicit package name at CombinedScript.pl line 307.
BEGIN not safe after errors--compilation aborted at CombinedScript.pl line 444